# Alljoyn Sink Ndk-Build

Tags: android, android-ndk, alljoyn

i'm try build lib. alljoyn audio sink, but have error when build this.

this eror :

```
[armeabi] Compile++ arm : AllJoynSink <= AndroidJNIBridge.cc
jni/AndroidJNIBridge.cc:18:35: fatal error: alljoyn/BusAttachment.h: No such file or directory
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/AllJoynAudioSink/AndroidJNIBridge.o] Error 1
```

Any solution? Thanks -Yossi-

Comment: Your include pahts are not set up correctly.

Comment: Yes, maybe. I'm started to learn alljoyn.. 
but i'm download this project from github.com/roa/audio/tree/master/samples/android/Sink/src/org/alljoyn/services/audio/sink
i'm trying build this project and still error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compile the AllJoyn Audio Service you will do so from the core/alljoyn folder per the instructions on the wiki page: https://wiki.allseenalliance.org/develop/downloading_the_source 
Next pull down the AllJoyn Audio Service into the services folder:

```
export AJ_ROOT=`pwd`/alljoyn
git clone https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/multimedia/audio.git $AJ_ROOT/services/
```

Now you are ready to compile AllJoyn and the Audio Service. To do that use the following and fill in the correct values for your system with [ ] meaning optional argument:

```
scons BINDINGS=core,cpp SERVICES=about,audio  OS=android CPU=arm ANDROID_NDK=<root of the nkd location> ANDROID_SRC=<root folder of android src> ANDROID_SDK=<root of the android sdk> [ANDROID_TARGET=<name of target if different then generic>] BUILD_SERVICES_SAMPLES=off WS=off
```

Now you have the liballjoyn_audio.so that you can place in the armeabi folder and you can compile the Android sample applications.

Source: https://ask.allseenalliance.org/question/154/unable-to-build-alljoyn-audio-service-framework-for-android/

Comment: thanks bro! i can build this. i'm edited from Android.mk for the directory.